# How do I enumerate sections with numbers and subsections with letters like this

Tags: formatting, counters

How do I enumerate sections with numbers and subsections with letters like this:

1. This is a section

   A. This is a subsection

   B. This is another subsection.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *Upper Case* letters as counter, use

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
```

For *lower case* letters, use `\alph` (as you could guess)!

There are other two options: `\Roman` or `\roman`

Comment: @Dion [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.